# PHP Function producing two iterations of an array, in the same array

Tags: php, class

I've got a function that gets data from a NoSQL database, and if it's not available then it goes to a MySQL database to get the data but the issue is, the function is putting the data into the array twice and I can't figure out why.

**Expected result**

```
array(2) { 
["id"]=> string(2) "30" 
["username"]=> string(8) "Username" }
```

**Actual result**

```
array(4) { 
[0]=> string(2) "30" 
["id"]=> string(2) "30" 
[1]=> string(8) "Username" 
["username"]=> string(8) "Username" }
```

**Code**

Code that is irrelevant to the problem is removed and replaced by pseudo code comments.

```
        $Connection = $this->Connect("MySQLi");
        $Data = MySQLi_Fetch_Array(

            MySQLi_Query($Connection["MySQLi"], $Options["Query"])

        );

        echo "Got array (MySQLi).";
```

It's worth noting that the string "Got array (MySQLi)." only appears once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysqli_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) takes a parameter, `resulttype`, which by default is set to `MYSQLI_BOTH`.

> By using the MYSQLI_ASSOC constant this function will behave identically to the mysqli_fetch_assoc(), while MYSQLI_NUM will behave identically to the mysqli_fetch_row() function. **The final option MYSQLI_BOTH will create a single array with the attributes of both.**

`mysqli_fetch_assoc` fetches an associative array, while `mysqli_fetch_row` fetches an array with numeric indexes.

`mysqli_fetch_array` with the parameter `MYSQLI_BOTH` will fetch both named (associative) indexes and numeric indexes in the same array.

Answer (score 2):

`MySQLi_Fetch_Array` gets duplicated data in one array - with numerical and associative indexes at the same time

Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead to have only associative